# What do these lights on my server mean? Has my HDD gone bad?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, raid-1, hp-proliant

So I got to work today after backing up this server over the weekend. I rebooted the server and it started running in the default windows OS and everything seemed to be working fine except for these lights. Normally, the red square, which is the eject button for the hotswap drives, stays dark like the drive on the bottom, however the drive on the bottom is flashing between green and orange on the HDD light. The two drives are in a hardware RAID 1 configuration, so they are mirrors of the other. I have new HDDs that I will be replacing all 8 of the old drive with by next weekend, however if there is a possibility of total failure between now and then, I would like to know in advance to make my CEO aware of the issue. Thank you in advance for your help, superusers!

[image: HDD Lights flashing Orange and green.]

Comment: What does the manual say?  I can't look it up since you didn't provide the manual (in English).

Comment: Make=hp proliant?, model number? Any information at all?

Comment: What is your RAID array status?  Is it running in a degraded state?

Comment: It is an HP Proliant DL360p Gen8
I am looking up the user manual now.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out. The manual says that the flashing green and yellow means that **the drive is predicted to fail**. Thank you for the helpful insights. I hadn't thought to check the manual. I'm not much for reading. the good news is that I should replace the drives before the issue devolves into being an actual problem.